# How to determine what cipher I encrypted a file with?

Tags: encryption, file-encryption, decryption

Years ago I had a bunch of bitcoin in a wallet that I encrypted. This was back when bitcoin was like $0.20 or $0.30 each. At one point I couple hundred of them but didn't know what to do with them. I lost the wallet & never really looked for it until the price skyrocketed especially digging for it when the price was at $20k but I never located it.

However, recently I got some old hard drives that had been stored at my parents for years and when looking through some of the drives I found a file btc.tar.gz.enc.

I don't remember creating this file but again it was so long ago and the coins were nearly worthless so I probably wouldn't. I have no idea how to open or decrypt the file...

I ran strings on it & I get this:

> zoidberg@PlanetExpress:/mnt/c/Users/Keith/Documents$ strings btc.tar.gz.enc
>   Salted__
>   s}mS'.
>   )hXe
>   eFeI
>   ?b`Z
>   OA&$>
>   %n&LBX
>   ?m)h;0+-
>   t$+D'
>   mIAi
>   h,|V
>   Fg.d

I don't know if this is a wallet with a decent amount of coins in it but even if it has a couple it would be awesome to get in there.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I may be able to figure out how to decrypt it? If I can figure that out I think I can eventually guess the password I used on it.

I'm assuming I used openssl but I don't know what cipher I used or anything.

If I'm able to open this and it has anything decent in there I will buy a very nice bottle of Whiskey for the gentleman/gentlewoman/insert pronoun here that provided the information. (I know people would help me just because people on here are great... But I would still do so if they wanted it).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you know the password? You can list ciphers using `openssl enc -ciphers` and try each one by doing: `openssl enc -d -in btc.tar.gz.enc -<cipher> 2>/dev/null`. Suppressing stderr output should mean that you only see a result if the cipher & password is correct.

Comment: @DanielA You are planning to guess the cipher, given a known good password.  I read the OP as meaning they were planning to guess the password given the cipher.  Of course, it is possible to write a little script which given a password tries all the ciphers, and then guess the password with that.  Given one bitcoin is worth $8000 atm, that's probably worthwhile.

Comment: Thank you! A friend of mine I talked to on facebook thinks it is AES-128-CBC. However, I tried that cipher with any password I can remember from that long ago and no luck. I'll try all the other ciphers as well cause as you said it's worth my time if I get in but I'm pretty sure I'm SOL.

I knew I had that wallet somewhere and I finally find it just to realize I'm probably never going to get into it LMAO.

*le sigh* at not having the foresight to realize how much bitcoin could possibly be worth someday.